# How to submit a form with more than one file field using blazor webassembly

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Please am working on a project using blazor webassembly that i want to submit a user's form and the form has more than one file upload fields with other input fields too. How do i process this form? I want the user to fill out this form, select all files and submit at once.

Comment: Is your project .net 5.0 or 3.1?

Comment: It is dotnet 3.2

Comment: InputFile does not exist in this version of blazor. Here is a link to the prototype. https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the [*InputFile*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0) component?

Then use can add the **multiple** attribute to the component to allow the user to upload multiple files as once.

Regarding submission of such a form you can create a model for holding the form data and then use **HttpClient** to send this to the backend.

[*This blog*](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/06473cc7-a391-409e-948d-3752ba3b4a6c.aspx) post seems to describe what you are trying to do.